# Is there a difference between a matte IPS or LCD display and glossy display with anti-glare screen protector?

Tags: laptop, display, lcd

Forgive me but I'm not so sure if this is an appropriate question to ask in this site. But is there a difference between a matte IPS or LCD display and a glossy display with anti-glare screen protector in terms of brightness, graininess (rainbow effect), and overall quality?